# How to deserializing xml into an object in c#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

This is the xml file, which I want to deserialize.

Having problems while deserializing some xml into an object in C#. 
TEST.XML

`<userMessage>
    <methodArguments>
    <entry>
        <key>text</key>
        <value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">TEST</value>
    </entry>
    </methodArguments>
    <methodName>relay:show:1</methodName>
</userMessage>`

I used xsd tools to generate this TEST.cs
I want to show XML value on console.

I want to do something like the one in this tutorial http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yojoshi/archive/2011/05/14/xml-serialization-and-deserialization-entity-classes-with-xsd-exe.aspx?Redirected=true 
i wrote this but i think its not correct
 class Program
    {

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (FileStream xmlStream = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\INI\\Desktop\\XML\\TEST.xml", FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(xmlStream))
            {



               XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(userMessage), new XmlRootAttribute("userMessage"));
               userMessage deserializedTest = serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader) as userMessage;
               foreach(var student in deserializedTest.methodName)
                {
                Console.WriteLine("aaaaaaaaa", student);


                Console.WriteLine("");
                }
            }
```

Comment: So what is that you tried out from the tutorial? You getting any kind of exception while deserializing?

Comment: I tried like the tutorial but its not show anything on console

Comment: Can you post your `userMessage` type?

Comment: what do u mean usermessage type>?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to deserialize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22757547/how-to-deserialize)

Comment: Please do **not** post duplicate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created a `UserMessage` Type and the code works fine. Cannot post what I did as a comment, so posting it as an answer. This might help you.

Here is the deserialze code

```
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer srl = new 
                 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(UserMessage));
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"D:\temp\test.xml");
var obj= srl.Deserialize(reader);
```

Here are the types.

```
[Serializable]
public class UserMessage
{
    public MethodArguments MethodArguments { get; set; }
    public string MethodName { get; set; }
}
public class MethodArguments
{
    public Entry Entry { get; set; }
}
public class Entry
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: where is the `userMessageMethodArgumentsEntry` definition? I checked that post and could not find the definition!